# Voip using sip from android app to web app

Tags: android, sip, voip, sip-server

I want to integrate voice and video call feature in my android as well as web app using sip.The scenario is like the end user can call from android app or web app to my support team which would be on web app.The scenario is similar to a call center where user call from app to support team.
I did some research on found lot of javascript and android sdks available but they don't provide cross platform functionality.Is there any open source library which could be used to achieve cross platform functionality and flexibility to use our own sip server.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Restcomm platform](http://www.restcomm.com/)

It contains [Android SDK](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk) that uses SIP, [Web SDK](https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-web-sdk) (that uses sip over websockets) and a Telephony Application SIP Server called [Restcomm-Connect](https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect) that allows you to build applications very easily through HTTP APIs or Visual Designer

Answer (score 0):

TBH, the only thing I found till now is Linphone. They use an [LibLinPhone](https://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone) SDK to implement things, but it is open sourced under GNU. I am still looking for other SDK alternatives, as they don't have the best documentation in the world.